# How to lighten a color map is sass

Tags: sass

I have created a color map as shown below and I am looking to use `lighten(color, amount)` every button when I hover over them.

the `@each` part of the code works and brings all of the colors over its the hover section that's not working.

```
`@each $button, $color in $button-colors{
    .btn#{$button}{
        background-color: $color;
    &:hover{
      background-color: lighten(get-map($button-colors), 15%);
    }
    }
  }`

`$button-colors:(
    '.default':#51ddfc,     
    '.error':  #e4757a,      
    '.info':   #927bc1,
    '.success':#63cc82,    
    '.warning':#fd7856,
);`
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You got the `get-map` function wrong. First of all it's `map-get`, and it has 2 parameters `$map` and `$key`. Read docs at https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/map.

There is no need to use `map-get` since you are already inside the loop and have access to the `$color`:

```
$button-colors: (
    '.default': #51ddfc,     
    '.error': #e4757a,      
    '.info': #927bc1,
    '.success': #63cc82,    
    '.warning': #fd7856
);

@each $button, $color in $button-colors{
  .btn#{$button}{
    background-color: $color;

    &:hover{
      background-color: lighten($color, 15%);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Syla, the map is in _variables partial separate to the "each code.  I don't want want to be constantly typing out the hover section.